# Opening content in new tab with banno-plugin-framework-bridge on mobile devices

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We're using the `banno-plugin-framework-bridge` package. Our goal is to open content in a new tab when a user clicks on a link in our plugin in the dashboard, and to open full screen on native mobile. According to the package's documentation, setting **`target="_blank"`** should do this, while `target="_top"` should open the content in an expanded view within the same window.

The problem I'm seeing is that, with `target="_top"`*,* the content is loaded in full screen in the same tab. The behavior in the native app seems to be what I'd expect on a Pixel device. But on some devices, the content opens in the `iframe` in the dashboard. Specifically, this issue occurs consistently on a Samsung S8 device, and frequently on one iPhone 12 but not on another.

If I set `target="_blank"`, it opens in a new tab on web, but within the dashboard `iframe` in the native app on the Pixel device. So it seems like the behavior is different between devices, and I might not be understanding the documentation properly.

Is there a known solution or workaround for this issue? Am I missing something in the documentation for the `banno-plugin-framework-bridge` package? To open content in full screen consistently on both web and native, which `target` value should I use?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The scenario is a bit confusing, so bear with us. Are you trying to do _different_ behaviors based on whether the user is in Banno Online vs Banno Mobile? It sounds like that's the case from the first paragraph: "Our goal is to open content in a new tab when a user clicks on a link in our plugin in the dashboard, and to open full screen on native mobile." If that's the case, that's not necessarily a scenario that would be supported and you may be seeing different behavior depending on _how_ you're identifying that the plugin is running in Banno Online vs Banno Mobile.

Comment: It's probably best to simplify down to a single way of handling things, and if I understand correctly it probably is best to use the Expanded View link for both Banno Online and Banno Mobile (https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/). If nothing else, that would narrow down any possible areas where things may be going awry (since we wouldn't also have to consider 'detect webview vs browser' behavior as a confounding factor).

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. Our goal is to open our app full screen when the user clicks a link in the card face. We don't necessarily care whether it opens in a new tab or not. Would you still recommend Expanded View (i.e. target is _top)? In that case, the problem we see is that it behaves differently on different devices. On my Android it works as expected. On one iPhone it works as expected, but on an identical iPhone it works periodically, and on a Samsung it doesn't work ever. What I mean by "doesn't work" is that it opens inside of the card face, instead of in full screen.

Comment: And when we set target to _blank, it stopped working properly on my Android. Again, that means it opened inside the card face instead of in full screen.

Comment: If you're looking to open the Expanded View, then yes it's best to use the `target="_top"` in your anchor tags so that the Plugin Bridge opens up the Expanded View.

Comment: The fact that it's not working as-is seems odd. It would be a good idea to remove any confounding factors by going to "Organize dashboard" in the Banno UI and hiding all of the cards (including other plugins and built-in cards like Transactions, Transfers, Support, Messages, etc) _except_ your own plugin. That'll narrow down any possibilities of a bug elsewhere.

Comment: Okay, we've removed all other dashboard cards but ours. And now it seems that whether target is `_blank` or `_top`, it consistently opens our content inside the `iframe` instead of in full screen. What might we be doing wrong?

Comment: Earlier you have mentioned that the behavior was different across different iPhone configs and different Android configs. Is that still true now that you've narrowed things down? Also, as of this writing the current version of Banno Mobile is `3.2` so you'll want to make sure that everywhere you're testing is up to date with that version of the mobile app.

Comment: Second thing that comes to mind is to narrow down network connectivity as a potential confounding factor. We have some content in the [Troubleshooting -> Network Connectity](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/troubleshooting/#network-connectivity) section on JackHenry.Dev.

Comment: Update: I think we've found a solution. Our UI framework by default loads 3rd-party scripts _after_ page interactivity. I changed it to load the Banno plugin script _before_ page interactivity. That seems to have fixed it. So it's a matter of when the Banno plugin JS loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I think we've found a solution. Our UI framework by default loads 3rd-party scripts *after* page interactivity. I changed it to load the Banno plugin script *before* page interactivity. That seems to have fixed it. So it's a matter of when the Banno plugin JS loads.